# Shared Memory Code Snippet in C

Tags: c, ipc, shared-memory

I came across the following code snippet

```
    int seg1 = shmget( number, 1, 0660 );
    if( -1 != seg1 )
    {
        struct shmid_ds buf;
        shmctl( seg1, IPC_RMID, &buf );
        fprintf( stderr, "Removed existing shared memory segment" );
    }
    int seg = shmget( number, 2 * size, IPC_CREAT | 0660 );
    Buffer =  (char*) shmat( seg, NULL, 0 );
```

Questions:

1) shmget( number, 1, 0660 )
f IPC_CREAT or IPC_EXCL is not specified and only 0660 is specified, what's the default IPC_ ? The does not explain this/

2) Why would one want to do a shmget for a key number with a size of 1 byte, then do a IPC_RMID and then again do a shmget of the same key with the bigger space ?

Comment: Please decide for *one* language, C or C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) shmget( number, 1, 0660 ) f IPC_CREAT or IPC_EXCL is not specified and only 0660 is specified, what's the default IPC_ ? The does not explain this/

By default, neither option applies. The segment is only opened if it already exists.

> 2) Why would one want to do a shmget for a key number with a size of 1 byte, then do a IPC_RMID and then again do a shmget of the same key with the bigger space ?

The purpose is just to remove an existing shared memory segment regardless of its size. The `shmget` function will fail if `size` is bigger than the size of the existing segment, so using one ensures it doesn't fail.

Comment: So, when we want to get hold of an existing shared mem region, the only use of the size is to ensure that we are not requesting above the previously allocated size ?